# remove text :last after()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-after

```
$('.main-bottom-menu li').after('<div style="float: left;">//</div>');
$('.main-bottom-menu li:last').after('');
```

but it doesn't clear `//` after last li element. How can i remove `//` after li:last element?

Comment: You are only inserting _nothing_.

Comment: I'd suggest `$('.main-bottom-menu li').parent().next('div').remove();` given that you're inserting invalid HTML; the ***only*** valid child of a `ul`, or `ol`, is an `li`. A `div` is *not* valid as the next-sibling of an `li`; so the browser will, likely, correct things as best it can, but unpredictably.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call [**remove()**](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) on selected element to remove it from DOM

**[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/37N5r/)**

**Change**

```
$('.main-bottom-menu li:last').after('');
```

**To**

```
$('.main-bottom-menu li:last').next('div').remove(); to remove div after last li
```

Comment: You guys misunderstood me, i don't want to remove LI from DOM, i want to removed "<div style="float: left;">//</div>" after last LI element! Thanks

Comment: I have updated my answer to remove div after last li from DOM and added live demo link, check it now.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
$('.main-bottom-menu li:last').html('');
```

According to this question, he doesn't want to remove the div, he just wants to empty it.  The above code should do it.